# Use ~/.ssh/config when opening streams with PHP SSH2

Tags: php, ssh, stream

Is it somehow possible to use a user's SSH client configuration when dealing with SSH2 streams in PHP? On most systems this is stored in ~/.ssh/config.

In my case I have several aliases configured in my SSH config. But, when I try to use those aliases in my PHP code they do not work.

Example ~/.ssh/config

```
Host foo
    HostName my.server
    Port 22
    User sander
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Example PHP code that fails, but that I'd like to get working:

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents('ssh2.sftp://foo/bar.txt');
```

Comment: Group permissions are going to get ridiculous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the source codes for the ssh2 wrapper at http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2 it seems they don not support aliases at all.

Post into their mailing list, the alias support could be probably easily added.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is perfectly possible. The file format of that file [is specified](http://www.squarebox.co.uk/cgi-squarebox/manServer/ssh_config.5). All you need to do is write a parser for it (maybe this has been written already, at least something similar) and then use you hostname (here: `foo`) to access that configuration.

Then you connect with these settings.

If you like to have exactly your example:

```
$text = file_get_contents('ssh2.sftp://foo/bar.txt');
```

This is more complicated and I think not even possible. However if you change the prefix, you should be able to inject your implementation as [a stream wrapper you register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php) which "wraps" around the ssh2 wrapper, so it's use is equally straight forward:

```
$text = file_get_contents('my.ssh2.sftp://foo/bar.txt');
```

Comment: That's a neat idea. Unfortunately I'm dealing with an external library that uses `file_get_contents()` so it's not easy to add a custom parser in it.

Comment: That is what stream wrappers are for.

Answer (score 2):

```php
$userName =username;

$password = password;

$domain = domain;

$connection = ssh2_connect($domain, 22);


ssh2_auth_password($connection, $userName, $password);
$sftp =ssh2_sftp($connection); 
$content = file_get_contents("ssh2.sftp://{$sftp}{$sourceFile}");
$data = $content ."new content";

$content = file_put_contents("ssh2.sftp://{$sftp}{$sourceFile}",$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

For php versions < 7 use intval()

```
$sftpConnection = ssh2_connect($host);
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($sftpConnection);
$fp = fopen("ssh2.sftp://" . intval($sftp) . $remoteFile, "r");
```

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73597